# Why might consonants have been thought of, as sounds only produced together with vowels?

Tags: historical-linguistics, consonants

> [consonant (n.)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=consonant&searchmode=none) [←] [...] from Latin  [...]
>   from *com-* "with" (see [com-](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=com-&allowed_in_frame=0)) + *sonare* "to sound" (see [sonata](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=sonata&allowed_in_frame=0)). Consonants were **thought of** as sounds that are only produced together with vowels.

Is last sentence false, because [this IPA Chart with Sounds](http://www.internationalphoneticalphabet.org/ipa-sounds/ipa-chart-with-sounds/) displays (and vocalises) consonants that can be pronounced alone? 
If so, which past nationality or peoples **thought of** consonants as above?    Why? [This](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/3369/5306) doesn't answer the above question.

<sub>PS: The above consists with *Linguistics For Dummies* (1 ed, 2012; by Déchaine, Burton, Vatikiotis-Bateson):</sub>

> <sub>[p 248:] Producing a speech sound requires an open vocal tract and airflow. This is
>   what vowels (like *a, e, i, o, u*) do — that’s why any vowel can be a syllable
>   by itself. Consonants (like *p, t, k, s, d*) constrict the vocal tract and typically
>   can’t be heard on their own. So it’s no wonder the most common syllable in the
>   world’s languages is the consonant plus vowel (CV) combination that gives us
>   words like *so, be, tea, too*.</sub>
>
> <sub>[p 250:] For example,
>   in most languages, vowels can stand alone as a syllable, but consonants
>   typically cannot. But languages make different decisions about which
>   consonants can be syllabic.</sub>

Comment: This could be a comment, but I don't have enough experence to post it as one. I don't think that this comepletely answers your question, but I know that Japanese usually follows a vowel then consonant pattern, as it uses a syllabary.

Comment: What examples make you say that /b/ and /d/ can be produced without vowels?

Comment: @JeremyNeedle See my edited OP please. Better? My guess may be wrong though.

Comment: I'm sorry, the linked chart doesn't explain this position to me. Every phone on the chart has a sound demo, but I don't see that it says any of them can be produced alone (without a vowel); indeed, almost all of these are produced with /a/. I asked about your /b/ and /d/ examples because one could say things like liquids, nasals, and fricatives can be produced alone, but in practice this isn't really the case either (few vowel-less words exist).

Comment: Syllables are natural units and they typically have consonants at the beginning and/or end with a vowel in the middle carrying the tone and stress information. Most consonants can't be intoned or stressed; only syllabic resonants can be syllable nuclei. The Latin grammarians weren't wrong; this was also the scheme hit on by the Sanskrit grammarians in developing their abugida; every consonant in Sanskrit has an underlying /a/ vowel after it. That's the name of the consonant and also the automatic pronunciation of the letter in writing; vowels are modifications of the consonant characters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Latin term is a calque from Greek σύμφωνον "pronounced with". According to [Dionysius Thrax](http://www.hs-augsburg.de/~harsch/graeca/Chronologia/S_ante02/DionysiosThrax/dio_tech.html#06), they "do not have a sound on their own, but, when arranged with vowels, they produce a sound". [Aristotle (poetics)](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:abo:tlg,0086,034:1456b:27&lang=original) expressed the same view of "mutes" being without sound of their own:

"Such sounds may be subdivided into vowel, semi-vowel, and mute. A vowel is that which without any addition has an audible sound; a semivowel needs the addition of another letter to give it audible sound, for instance S and R; a mute is that which with addition has no sound of its own but becomes audible when combined with some of the letters which have a sound. Examples of mutes are G and D."

In Sanskrit grammatical tradition, vowels are *svara* meaning "sound", and consonants are *vyañjana*, meaning "ornamentation" (also "sauce" and a bunch of other things). So the view that you're pointing to probably originates with Aristotle, with terminology supplied by Dionysius.

Answer (score 0):

In most languages a syllable must consist of at least one vowel and zero or more consonants. While you can *pronounce* a consonant in isolation most languages require *syllables* and *words* to contain vowels. Syllabic sonorants like in *bottle* and *button* aren't really counterexamples, because sonorants are, well, sonorous enough to function as syllable nuclei, but very few languages permit syllables consisting entirely of obstruents.